# How to fix menu links going below the fold?

Tags: 8, navigation

How do you fix menu links in the admin toolbar (drop down menus) from going below the fold when you have many different bundles?

For example, the "Paragraph Types" submenus often go below the fold because they sit alphabetically low on the "Configuration" drop-down.  If you have many paragraph types, it's hard to access them from the drop-down submenus.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new dropdown under the entity type ("Paragraphs types") that groups the links by first letter. Also, you can can change the weight of your item, and even move it out of being nested under configuration.

In the following example, we look for all the children of 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection' and we nest them under a copy of 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection' labeled with the first letter of the paragraphs underneath it.

```
function mymodule_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {

  $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection']['weight'] = 8;
  $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection']['parent'] = 'system.admin';

  foreach($links as $key => $link) {
    if (!empty($link['parent']) && $link['parent'] == 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection') {
      $first_letter = substr($link['title']->render(),0, 1);
      $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection.' . $first_letter] = [
        'title' => $first_letter,
        'route_name' => 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection',
        'menu_name' => 'admin',
        'parent' => 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection'
      ];
      $links[$key]['parent'] = 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection.' . $first_letter;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the same alphabetical grouping technique on vocabularies:

```
    foreach($links as $key => $link) {
      if (!empty($link['parent']) && $link['parent'] == 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection') {
        $first_letter = substr($link['title']->render(),0, 1);
        $links['entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection.' . $first_letter] = [
          'title' => $first_letter,
          'route_name' => 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection',
          'menu_name' => 'admin',
          'parent' => 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection'
        ];
        $links[$key]['parent'] = 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection.' . $first_letter;
      }
    }
```

[image]

If you move the paragraph types to it's own drop-down, as in the example above, you'll want to style an icon for it.

```
.toolbar-icon-entity-paragraphs-type-collection:before,
.toolbar-icon-entity-paragraphs-type-collection:active:before,
.toolbar-icon-entity-paragraphs-type-collection.is-active:before {
  background-image: url(../../../../core/themes/stable/images/core/icons/787878/wrench.svg);
}
```

Here's my current version, which adds an "Add Paragraph Type" link:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_links_discovered_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {

  // Move paragraphs to its own drop down.
  $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection']['weight'] = -7;
  $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection']['parent'] = 'system.admin';
  $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection']['title'] = 'Paragraphs';

  // Move taxonomy to its own drop down.
  $links['entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection']['weight'] = -7;
  $links['entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection']['parent'] = 'system.admin';
  $links['entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection']['title'] = 'Taxonomy';

  $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection.add'] = [
    'title' => new TranslatableMarkup('Add Paragraph Type'),
    'route_name' => 'paragraphs.type_add',
    'menu_name' => 'admin',
    'parent' => 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection',
    'weight' => -100,
  ];

  // Break paragraphs into groups by starting letter.
  foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
    if (!empty($link['parent']) && $link['parent'] == 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection') {
      $first_letter = substr($link['title']->render(), 0, 1);

      $links['entity.paragraphs_type.collection.' . $first_letter] = [
        'title' => $first_letter,
        'route_name' => 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection',
        'menu_name' => 'admin',
        'parent' => 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection',
      ];
      $links[$key]['parent'] = 'entity.paragraphs_type.collection.' . $first_letter;
    }
  }

  foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
    if (!empty($link['parent']) && $link['parent'] == 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection') {
      $first_letter = substr($link['title']->render(), 0, 1);
      $links['entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection.' . $first_letter] = [
        'title' => $first_letter,
        'route_name' => 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection',
        'menu_name' => 'admin',
        'parent' => 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection',
      ];
      $links[$key]['parent'] = 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.collection.' . $first_letter;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a second answer, because I've been adjusting my code above, and discovered you can create a custom toolbar to house your paragraph links.  I have created a custom module that does it for you:

https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_toolbar